# How to design a dynamic and modular system (Python)

Tags: python

I'm currently designing a chat bot for sake of brevity here's a simplified version of what I have.

A main module

```py
import bot
<import Command>
bot.connect()
def msg_handler(msg):
    
bot.handle_message(Command.handler)
bot.start()
```

A command module

```py
def handler(msg):
    if msg.startswith("!"):
        prefix,rest = get_command_prefix(msg)
        if prefix in <handlers>:
            <handlers>[prefix](rest)
```

Multiple specific commands for example

```py
<register>
def echo(msg):
    send(msg)
```

So my question is how to connect these together

specifically how do i register the various commands to a central module which has shared code

Some options I have considered

giving each module an `init` function which registers it

```py
def init(registry):
    registry.register(name,handler)
```

some disadvantages are that most init functions will be almost the same and it's very explicit

decorator and import

```py
import Registry

@Registry.register
def echo(...):
   ...
```

Here the problem would be if the registry moves or changes slightly it could mean changing each command

Some final notes

- one does not know how many modules there are at runtime
- i'm trying to minimize code duplication
- it would be nice to be able to load additional modules at runtime
- a similar problem arises between command.py and main.py so a hierarchical or multi level solution would be nice

is there a general/know approach to this sort of problem

**EDIT**

A small after thought is that the specific "command.py" might differ for example a normal version and a testing version which might make my second proposal not as applicable